# Insertar decimales desde php a phpMyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

como estan?
Tengo una duda, quiero ingresar un valor desde php, como por ejemplo 155.60, pero al agregarlo a la base de datos de phpMyadmin, me la guarda como 155, osea, lo redondea, pero necesito si o si la presicion. Coloque FLOAT en la BD, tambien probe con REAL y DOUBLE. Pero hace lo mismo.
Este es mi código desde php:

```
    $sql="insert into productos (idProducto,Nombre_Producto, precio, Detalles, id_Tipo_Moneda,
                                    id_Categoria, Stock, idEstadoEliminacion, CantidadAlarma )values(:codProd,:nombre, :pre, :det, :tmoneda,
                                    :cat, :stock, :estelim, :Alarma)";

                                    $sentencia = $con->prepare($sql);
                                    $sentencia-> bindParam(':codProd', $codProd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                    $sentencia-> bindParam(':nombre', $nom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                    $sentencia-> bindParam(':pre', $pre, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                                    $sentencia-> bindParam(':det', $det, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                    $sentencia-> bindParam(':tmoneda', $tMoneda, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                    $sentencia-> bindParam(':cat', $cat, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                                    $sentencia-> bindParam(':stock', $stock, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                                    $sentencia-> bindParam(':estelim', $estel, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                                    $sentencia-> bindParam(':Alarma', $Alarma, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Alguien me podría ayudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para guardar datos con decimales con una mayor presición; debes utilizar el tipo de dato  `DECIMAL()` el cual te va a solicitar lo siguiente:

```
DECIMAL(A, B);
```

1. A es el número máximo de espacio que la columna tendrá
2. B es el número tomado para hacer la presición

Los datos numéricos que requieren mayor grado de precisión como lo son: precios o unidades monetarias bancarias

**EXPLICACIÓN**

Si por ejemplo tus cantidades fueran siempre del rango siguiente:

```
desde 100.00
hasta 999.99
```

Entonces la declaración de tu columna debería ser:

```
precio DECIMAL(5, 2)
```

Donde la estamos indicando que habrá un total de 5 cifras para los valores ingresados en la columna precio, pero que 2 de ellos serán ocupados para almacenar los números decimales del registro de cada `precio`

**aclaración**

Dentro de la estructura de tu código PHP, tienes una columna por llenar llamada `precio` que después tratas de este modo:

```
$sentencia-> bindParam(':pre', $pre, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Lo anterior es incorrecto, por que si estas esperando un precio con decimales, el tipo de dato `INT` no nos ayuda entonces debes cambiarlo por

```
$sentencia-> bindParam(':pre', $pre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Por que sería la aproximación mas cercana para tratar un tipo de dato con decimales

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!! aprendi algo nuevo y funcionó genial. Te agradezco!!